# SQL count column and list values counted

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am trying to create a query that will output a count of a column and then list the names it counted:

Table 1: license_granted

```
users      checkout  
Bob        2014-11-18 01:00:00  
Steve      2014-11-18 01:00:00
Bob        2014-11-18 01:30:00
Chris      2014-11-18 01:30:00
```

I am able to do my count and get this output:

```
checkout_time            ctUsers  
2014-11-18 01:00:00         2
2014-11-18 01:30:00         2

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users) AS ctUsers, checkout
FROM license_granted
GROUP BY checkout
```

What I would like to get is:

```
checkout_time            ctUsers     userlist
2014-11-18 01:00:00         2        Bob,Steve
2014-11-18 01:30:00         2        Bob,Chris
```

Can this be done in the query?

Thanks

UPDATE 11/20 Okay I dug a little further and found a solution that gives me the checkout time and the userlist.  Now I am trying to figure out how to count the elements in the userlist:

```
SELECT a.ctDate, SUBSTRING(d.users,1, LEN(d.users) - 1) usersList, count(d.users) AS ctUsers
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(10), deniedTime, 126) AS ctDate
    FROM hyperworks_checkouts
    ) a
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT [username] + ', ' 
        FROM hyperworks_checkouts AS B 
        WHERE A.ctdate = convert(varchar(10), deniedTime, 126)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) d (users)
```

The output now looks like this:

```
ctDate        usersList
2014-01-15    Bob
2014-01-16    Steve,Bob
2014-01-17    Mike,Chris,Jerry
```

If I try adding COUNT(d.users) in the Select I get a count of 1 each time because there is one list.  How do I count the users in d.users?

Thanks

Comment: You you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Regardless, you can google "<database> aggregate string concatenation" and have your choice of methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function is what you are looking for.

So for your example, try:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users) AS ctUsers, checkout, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT users)
FROM license_granted
GROUP BY checkout
```

You can also define a custom separator for the `GROUP_CONCAT` values by adding a `SEPARATOR` clause inside the GROUP_CONCAT query, ie. `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT users SEPARATOR ' '`

Comment: thanks for the post chuck. can you elaborate on this to help prevent the answer losing its value if the link ever breaks? e.g. perhaps edit the answer and add an example usage of group_concat for the user. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks Chuck.  I end up getting an error 'GROUP_CONCAT is not a recognized aggregate function.

Comment: FYI I am using SQL-Server 2012

Comment: The original post was flagged with both mysql and sql-server.  GROUP_CONCAT is probably a mysql only solution. Best of luck~

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.  After looking at a few postings I was able to piece together the solution I needed:

```
SELECT a.ctDate, SUBSTRING(d.users,1, LEN(d.users) - 1) usersList, 
    (select len(d.users) - len(replace(d.users, ',', ''))) AS ctUsers
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(10), deniedTime, 126) AS ctDate
    FROM hyperworks_denials
    ) a
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT [username] + ', ' 
        FROM hyperworks_denials AS B 
        WHERE A.ctdate = convert(varchar(10), deniedTime, 126)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) d (users)
```

Thanks everyone that gave suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try following query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users) AS ctUsers, checkout,to_char(wm_concat(users)) Name
FROM license_granted
GROUP BY checkout
```